# how does strip() method works with append() method?

Tags: python, list, append, readline, strip

When I run the following script

```
WORD_URL = http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt
WORDS = []
for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readline():
    WORDS.append(word.strip())
print WORDS
```

python gives the following output:

['a', 'c', 'c', 'o', 'u', 'n', 't', '']

I am confused on how does strip() method works with append() method? Also how does readline() acts in this script?

Comment: Don't do `readline` do `readlines`

Comment: Well, does it work now?

Comment: no it gives the same result

Comment: Do this: change your for loop to `for word in word_list:` and right before your for loop, add this line: `word_list = urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines()` and `print word_list`. Then tell me the output.

Comment: account

account

account

account

account

account

account

account

Comment: every account is in different line and there is a space of one line between each of them

Comment: I have updated my answer to solve your problem, the script works now and gives proper output. It has two `print` statements: one before and one after the `strip()` method so you can see what the `strip()` does.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strip()` method takes whatever string you have and removes trailing whitespaces and newline characters

```
>>> '   asdfadsf '.strip()
'asdfadsf'

>>> '\nblablabla\n'.strip()
'blablabla'

>>> a = []
>>> a.append('   \n asdf \n    '.strip())
>>> a
['asdf']

>>> words = [' a ', '   b    ', '\nc\n']
>>> words = [word.strip() for word in words]
>>> words
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

## Updated Answer to Updated Question

```
from urllib import urlopen

WORD_URL = 'http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt'
WORDS = []
word_list = urlopen(WORD_URL)
word_list = word_list.readlines()
print word_list                      # before strip()
for word in word_list:
    WORDS.append(word.strip())
print WORDS                          # after strip(), so you get an idea of what strip() does
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method is actually applied on `word`, which is a string. As `strip` removes the whilespace characters around the `word`, the resulting string is added to the `WORDS`.

You can use List Comprehension (which is more efficient than normal looping) like this

```
[word.strip() for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines()]
```